# Configure Azure App Service Automatic Scaling based on incoming traffic

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

We are trying to use elastic scale feature of Azure App service which is automatically scale out the number of running instances of your application to keep up with the flow of incoming HTTP requests, and automatically scale in your application by reducing the number of running instances when incoming request traffic slows down. Below is the Azure CLI command.

```
az resource update -g <<resource group name>> -n <<app service plan name>> --set properties.ElasticScaleEnabled=1 --resource-type Microsoft.Web/serverfarms
```

Now the question is, do we have any specific number for incoming traffic like after how many incoming requests its deciding to add more instances or remove instances? Is this something that we can configure or control on our end?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/azure-app-service-automatic-scaling/ba-p/2983300), I would understand that the scaling decisions are taken by the service and cannot be influenced by the user. If you want to have more fine-grained control, you can use the classical AppService [AutoScaling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/autoscale/autoscale-get-started).